# Node size of body diode connections in transistors

Tags: circuitikz

I need to change the circle node size of the bodydiode to adjust it to the rest of the nodes, but I haven't found any documentation from the `circuitikz` package to do that.

From this example code:

```tex
\documentclass[]{standalone}

\usepackage[americanvoltages]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}%

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tikzset{%
            actsw/.style={%
                nigfete,%
                bodydiode,%
                solderdot,%
            },%
        }%
        \draw[] (0,0)node[ocirc](){} node[actsw,anchor=D] (n_sw){};
        \ctikzset{nodes width=0.03,}
        \draw[] (1.5,0)node[ocirc](){} node[actsw,anchor=D,scale=0.8] (n_sw){};
        \ctikzset{nodes width=0.06,}
        \draw[] (3,0)node[ocirc](){} node[actsw,anchor=D,scale=0.8] (n_sw){};
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}%
```

I get this:

[image: TeX]

Comment: Hi, welcome! I opened a feature request issue on GitHub related to this question: https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/issues/720

Comment: PR ready: https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/pull/726

Comment: Nice! Thank you and the rest of the circuitikz team for your work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no option to scale the body diode connection dots or the solder dots; I have prepared a [feature request](https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/issues/720) (please comment if you want).

For the moment, you can just superimpose nodes to the connections using the anchors.

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}

\usepackage[americanvoltages]{circuitikz}
\newcommand\addbodycirc[1]{
    \node [circ] at (#1.body C in){};
    \node [circ] at (#1.body E in){};
    \node [circ] at (#1.inner down){};
}
\begin{document}%

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tikzset{% no need to escape end-of-lines --- they're ignored here
            actsw/.style={
                nigfete,
                bodydiode,
                solderdot,
            },
        }
        \draw[] (0,0)node[ocirc](){} node[actsw,anchor=D] (n_sw){};
        \addbodycirc{n_sw}
        \ctikzset{nodes width=0.03,}
        \draw[] (1.5,0)node[ocirc](){} node[actsw,anchor=D,scale=0.8] (n_sw){};
        \addbodycirc{n_sw}
        \ctikzset{nodes width=0.06,}
        \draw[] (3,0)node[ocirc](){} node[actsw,anchor=D,scale=0.8] (n_sw){};
        \addbodycirc{n_sw}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice that the problem with `ocirc` is expected because the `ocirc` node is painted *before* the `nigfete` node. It can be fixed in several ways, but the cleanest is explicitly drawing the `ocirc` *after* the node.

Notice that the solder dot difference is because you are using `scale=0.8`, which will scale *all* the node (this is a Ti*k*Z overriding option). If you want to have the solder dot of the same size as the normal `circ` nodes, you need to scale only the transistor using the class `transistor/scale` parameter.

```latex
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage[americanvoltages]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}%
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzset{% no need to escape end-of-lines --- they're ignored here
        actsw/.style={
            nigfete,
            bodydiode,
            solderdot,
            anchor=D,
        },
    }

    \draw[] (0,4) node[circ]{} node[actsw] (A){} 
    ++(2,0) node[circ]{} node[actsw,scale=0.7](As){}
    ++(2,0) node[circ]{} node[actsw,circuitikz/transistors/scale=0.7](As){}
    ;
    \ctikzset{nodes width=0.03,}
    \draw[] (0,2) node[circ]{} node[actsw] (B){}
    ++(2,0) node[circ]{} node[actsw,scale=0.7](Bs){}
    ++(2,0) node[circ]{} node[actsw,circuitikz/transistors/scale=0.7](Bs){}
    ;
    \ctikzset{nodes width=0.06,}
    \draw[] (0,0) node[circ]{} node[actsw] (C){}
    ++(2,0) node[circ]{} node[actsw,scale=0.7](Cs){}
    ++(2,0) node[circ]{} node[actsw,circuitikz/transistors/scale=0.7](Cs){}
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But frankly, seeing the results, I think I will add options to the transistors class to choose the scale of the solder and bodydiode dots; my opinion is that they should be smaller than the normal `circ` (because they are marking an *internal* connection, not user-made ones), but I'll let the option for tuning them.

Comment: Glad to read such a complete answer, thank you!. Well, in fact, the idea is to scale the `circuitikz` environment without scaling the whole picture (for a double-column-paper-size article) in order to be consistent with the font sizes and such, but after a certain size the internal nodes become just too small to be identified from the naked eye; and after reading how customizable `circuitikz` is nowadays, I just wondered if there was an option to customize the bodydiode connection nodes in a modular (using `foo/.style=`) way.

Comment: Besides, it would be also good to be coherent in terms of node sizes for the `solderdot` feature (which is also an internal connection) and the `bodydiode` nodes.

Comment: Yes, if you look at the GitHub feature request linked, that's my plan.

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[americanvoltages]{circuitikz}

\makeatletter
\def\rlen{\pgf@circ@Rlen}
\makeatother

\begin{document}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node[ocirc] at (0,0) {};
      \node[circle,draw,inner sep=1.13pt] at (0.2,0) {};
      \draw (0.4,0) circle[radius={\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/nodes width}*\rlen}];
      \draw (0.6,0) circle[radius={0.04*\rlen}];
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]